# Vaadin 14 popup with button and context menu

Tags: vaadin

I want to have a context menu like this [Basic ContextMenu](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-context-menu/java-examples), that shows on button click. Each of the entries of the context menu should open a new window.

```
 private void button_onClick(final ClickEvent<Button> event)
    {
        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        contextMenu.addItem("Start", e -> this.add(new Dialog(new Start())));
        contextMenu.addItem("Stop", e -> this.add(new Dialog(new Stop())));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't call `open()` on the dialog.

```
private void button_onClick(final ClickEvent<Button> event)
{
    final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.addItem("Start", e -> this.add(new Dialog(new Start()).open()));
    contextMenu.addItem("Stop", e -> this.add(new Dialog(new Stop()).open()));
}
```

Comment: Dialogs don't have to be added. just open them. `contextMenu.addItem("Start", e -> new Dialog(new Start()).open());`

Comment: you define the context menu, but you do nothing with it. You need to set its target using `contextMenu.setTarget(targetComponent)`. You know, there are great documentation with examples about all of this, please at least try to find out such questions before asking. [All Vaadin Components](https://vaadin.com/components), [Java examples of ContextMenu](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-context-menu/java-examples)

Comment: by setting the target, the contextMenu will pop up when you right-click the target component. I'm not sure what `setOpenOnClick(true)` does, as I have never used a ContextMenu myself yet. My guess is that when you `setOpenOnClick(true);`, the Contextmenu will open not when **right**-clicking but by **left**-clicking. You still need to have a target set for this.

Comment: Please notice that with the current implementation, it will add another ContextMenu to the Button each time you click it. Define the contextmenu only once and outside the clicklistener of the button (you don't even need a clicklistener for the button)

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button button = new Button("context button");
final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.setOpenOnClick(true); //on left click
contextMenu.setTarget(button); //link button
contextMenu.addItem("xls", event -> Notification.show("xls"));
contextMenu.addItem("pdf", event -> Notification.show("pdf"));
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?